# Missing POM when referencing GridGain from IntelliJ as maven library

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, gridgain

I try to reference GridGain in IntelliJ IDEA with the following maven coordinates:
org.gridgain:gridgain-core:6.5.2

However when files are being downloaded into ~/.m2 I get:

[WARNING] Missing POM for org.gridgain:gridgain-core:jar:6.5.2
... from intellij.
Does anyone know if this is really the IDE error, or something is fishy with GridGain?

Thank you,
Eugene.

Comment: Usually an either it's the wrong version or during the download things have gone wrong but without the full erorr output best from console it's hard to guess.

Comment: Can you change the version to 6.5.5 and try again?

Comment: I am seeing the jar available on [maven central here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.gridgain%7Cgridgain-core%7C6.5.2%7Cjar).

Comment: I tried 6.5.5 with the same (lack of) result.

Comment: Also it works ok from sbt (which unfortunately downloads to ~/.ivy)

Comment: It seems like something in your environment does not like maven central.

Comment: It looks like this is a bug with intellij, CLI works like a charm. Sorry for the false alarm.